# How to remove line-height from top of text?

Tags: html, css, fonts, text-alignment

I am using a left floated image next to text with a line-height of 2.

How can I align the top of the image to the top of the text?

- Collapsing the space created by the line-height (marked in red in the
  below screenshot) by reducing the line-height to 1 or smaller for all
  of the text is not an option for this project.
- This will also be part of the default styling used in the website's
  content so adjusting the margin manually for each occurrence is not
  feasible.
- This is not a single case scenario. There may be only text, only an
  image, image followed by text, or text follow by image. The text may
  be a header or paragraph.

Is there a way to remove the top of the line-height and double the bottom of the line-height?

[image: Markup of issue]

```css
.left {
  float:left;
}
.text {
  line-height:2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="left" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3h4es7ma/2/)

- While the `::first-line` pseudo-element does come close to what I'm
  trying to do, it does not work to reduce line-height in Firefox nor does
  it provide the correct line-height between the first line and second
  line of text when wrapped. Seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dqmu8/25/

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do this properly, except measuring the height of the text with JS, subtracting that from the line-height and adding a negative margin.

Comment: @Oriol I was hoping for a CSS solution, however if that is not possible, can you answer with a JS solution that would work with most fonts whether in paragraphs or headers?

Comment: I believe you need to review what line height actually is and why you can't remove it from just the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this you mean?

With image

```css
.left {
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.text {
  line-height:2;
}
div img + .text {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="left" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Without image

```css
.left {
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.text {
  line-height:2;
}
div img + .text {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct result, however only text next to an image (image floated left or right) should be aligned this way. If only text is displayed, I don't want the margin adjusted.

Comment: @block14 Am following up on older answers and found this. Did my update solved it in the way you wanted?

Comment: This is probably the closest to what I ended up with. I made a list of line-height fixes like: `.clearfix img.left + h3 {margin-top:-.5em}`. Some day if `has` becomes adopted into CSS I will make the change.

Comment: @block14 Okay, great ... and thanks for reply and accept.

Answer (score 1):

Add this style:

```
.text {
  transform: translateY(-0.6em);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hhjfkLvy/1/)

Comment: Excellent property, I didn't think to use this one instead of having to use margins! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Look at this. Is it what you need?

```css
.left {
  float:left;
  margin-top: .5em;
}
.text {
  line-height:2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="left" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a solution that will also affect headers? https://jsfiddle.net/3h4es7ma/3/

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer, you should add a negative .5em top margin to the text though.

Comment: @block14 Yes, to work with whatever type of text element you have, put the image inside the text element.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.left {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.content p {
  line-height: 2;
}

.content img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img class="left" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p></p>
  <img class="right" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p></p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Line height of 2 will put 1/2 an `em` above the line and 1/2 an `em` below the line.  So you just need to subtract the 1/2 em from the text's top margin, and add it back on the image.  If you place the image within the text's flow, it will work regardless of block type :

**`<p>`**

```css
.left {
  float:left;
  margin-top:.5em;
}
.text {
  line-height:2;
  margin-top:-.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="text">
     <img class="left" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

**`<h1>`**

```css
.left {
  float:left;
  margin-top:.5em;
}
.text {
  line-height:2;
  margin-top:-.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="text">
     <img class="left" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </h1>
</div>
```